# Machine learning algorithms as matrix factorization

Tags: machine-learning, references, matrix-decomposition

I came to know that various ML algorithms can be posed a matrix factorization problems with different constraints specific to that particular problem. Is there any good material that provides an overview for frequently used ML algorithms(PCA,Kmeans etc ) at one place.

Answer (score 7):

[Generalized Low Rank Models](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/glrm.pdf) paper deals with exactly this.

From the abstract:

> This framework
>   encompasses many well known techniques in data analysis, such as
>   nonnegative matrix factorization, matrix completion, sparse and robust PCA,
>   k-means, k-SVD, and maximum margin matrix factorization.

Comment: And there is also linked code: [LowRankModels.jl](https://github.com/madeleineudell/LowRankModels.jl).